# How can I scroll up the "success messag div" using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my user page I've a button which is show a popup box with a form. After fill up the form I process it with Jquery/Ajax and get the success message.

But problem is Success Message is not shown. **It's gone to up.** I just see a blank page. **But it's showing the success message if i scroll it to up.** it's should be show the success message box on the screen without scroll by manually.

Following is my code which I'm working..

**Register Button where I click:**

```
<a id="join_now" class="big-link2" data-reveal-id="myModal2">Register</a>
```

**Form is showing after click the button**

```
<div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal3">
<span style="float:right; cursor:pointer;"><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></span>

<div id="formError">
</div>

<form id="campaign" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("campaing_process.php"); ?> ">
<table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Work phone number <span><sup>*</sup></span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="tr_medium" placeholder="Work phone number" /></td>
  </tr>

  <!--There are more fields it's bigger than browser -->     

  <tr>  
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="GET THE KIT" class="submit_button" /></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</form>
```

**Success/Error Message is showing on this div box**

```
<div id="formError">
</div>
```

**Update Jquery/Ajax Call:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#campaign").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.action,
            type: form.method,
            //async: false,
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            beforeSend : function (){
              $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true); 
            },
            success: function(response) {
            $('#formError').html(response);
            $(form).hide();
            //return false;

            setTimeout(function() {
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
            location.reload();
            }, 5000 );  
            }            
        });
    },

        rules: {
            phone: "required",
            postal: "required",
            suburb: "required",
            state: "required",
            pcode: "required",      
            terms : "required",
            terms1 : "required",                

            purpose: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 150
                },
            workforce: {
                required: true, 
                maxlength : 150
                },
            plan_implement : {
                required: true, 
                maxlength : 150
                },                      
        },
        messages: {
            terms : "Required",
            terms1 : "Required",

            phone : "Required",
            postal: "Required",
            suburb: "Required",
            state: "Required",
            pcode: "Required",
            purpose: {
                required: "Required",
                maxlength: "Only 150 characters allowed"
                },
            workforce :  {
                required: "Required",
                maxlength: "Only 150 characters allowed"
                },
            plan_implement :  {
                required: "Required",
                maxlength: "Only 150 characters allowed"
                },

        }
    });


});
</script>
```

Comment: missing javascript V_V

Comment: @Infer-On I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: where is your jquery/Ajax call which you say?

Comment: you can hit $('#formError').html(response)? what is the _response_ value?

Comment: @Infer-On It's showing the Message from php page. Actually It's only showing Success Message because I'm validating this form using Jquery Plugin.